# Secrets doesnt pass from github action secrets to reusable workflow in github actions

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, terraform, github-actions

I created secrets in github actions and trying to use them in reusable workflow, but I am unable to make it work, However, If I pass secrets hardcoded from caller file, it works just fine

```
## set_env.yml
name: Sent Env Creds and Vars

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
      - dev
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]

jobs:
  deploy-dev:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/main.yml
    with:
      AWS_REGION: "us-east-2"
      PREFIX: "dev"
    secrets:
      AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.DEV_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
      AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.DEV_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
```

reusable workflow = main.yml

```
## main.yml
name: Deploy to AWS  

# Controls when the workflow will run
on:
  workflow_call:
    inputs:
      AWS_REGION:
        required: true
        type: string
      PREFIX:
        required: true
        type: string
    secrets:
      AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID:
        required: true
      AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY:
        required: true

# A workflow run is made up of one or more jobs that can run sequentially or in parallel
jobs:
  terraform-deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    # Steps represent a sequence of tasks that will be executed as part of the job
    steps:
      # # Checks-out your repository under $GITHUB_WORKSPACE, so your job can access it
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      # Runs a set of commands using the runners shell
      - name: Run a multi-line script
        run: | 
                echo Hello, Epsilon! You are in ${{ inputs.AWS_REGION }} region ${{ inputs.PREFIX }} region 
                for dir in $(ls -l | grep '^d' | awk '{print $9}'); do
                    PARENT_DIR=`pwd`
                    echo $dir
                    cd $dir
                    terraform init -backend-config=${PARENT_DIR}/${{ inputs.PREFIX }}-backend.tfvars
                    terraform validate
                    terraform plan -var-file=${{ inputs.PREFIX }}_vars.tfvars
                    ## terraform apply -input=false -auto-approve -var-file=${{ inputs.PREFIX }}_vars.tfvars
                    cd ..
                done
        env:
          AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
          AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
```

If I hardcode secrets in set_env.yml while calling main.yml like below, it just works

```
  jobs:
      deploy-dev:
        uses: ./.github/workflows/main.yml
        with:
          AWS_REGION: "us-east-2"
          PREFIX: "dev"
        secrets:
          AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: <harcoded value>
          AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: <hardcoded value>
```

I have been trying to make it work in many ways but doesnt work. Please help

Comment: There's a ready-made GitHub action for Terraform: https://github.com/marketplace/actions/hashicorp-setup-terraform.

Comment: @MarkoE that uses terraform cloud, but we are not

Comment: You don't have to use the TF Cloud setup if you don't want to. I configured it so it fits my needs. Also: `Credentials for Terraform Cloud (app.terraform.io) __can__ be configured.`

Comment: @MarkoE The way I have structured is, I have multiple directories 1 per aws service like vpc, compute etc. I loop into every directory and run terraform commands (init, plan etc).

Also, I have configured secrets in github action secrets, so I can import appropraite secrets depending on environment we want to deploy.

is there a way we can accomplish that usin my current code.
do you think of any issue why I can't read secrets in my code from github actions secrets (as harcoding them, they are just passed fine to reusable workflow)

Comment: This is likely a GH permissions/organization issue. Ensure that the secrets are available and accessible for this Action.

Comment: Are you even able to call the `uses: ./.github/workflows/main.yml` in your workflow without having the `uses: actions/checkout@v2.3.4` step first? You should need it to access the reusable workflow, as it is located in the same repository.

Comment: @GuiFalourd yes, I am able to call the workflow. Even, if I hardcode creds in caller, it just works fine. probelm starts where I try to use secrets from github-actions/screts

Comment: @MattSchuchard secrets are available for sure. can you please suggest how can I configure the access for them so that they become available for the action

Comment: Instead of using `uses: ./.github/workflows/main.yml` in the `set_env.yml` workflow, did you try with `owner/repo/.github/workflows/main.yml@main`? (This is how they do it in the [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows#example-caller-workflow)).

Comment: Maybe the [new (May 2022) keyword `secrets: inherit`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72103477/6309) could help?

Answer (score 10):

As of May 3rd 2022, this is now possible with the new keyword `inherit`: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onworkflow_callsecretsinherit

In the calling workflow, you tell it to inherit the secrets in the reusable workflow:

```yaml
jobs:
  deploy-dev:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/main.yml
    with:
      AWS_REGION: "us-east-2"
      PREFIX: "dev"
    secrets: inherit
```

This makes the secrets available in the reusable workflow like normal:

```yaml
with:
  myInput: ${{ secrets.MY_SECRET }}
```

Note that there's no need to declare the secrets on the `workflow_call` trigger.

Comment: This does not answer the question. OP is trying to pass secret values that are specific to an environment DEV_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and map them to a generic name in the reusable workflow AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, likely for reuse across envs

Comment: Upvoted, good information but apparently not universally true. Maybe it doesn't work for old secrets. So maybe secret sometimes need recreate. as @SemajDraw suggest. I didn't try though because I don't know these secrets and don't care enough to extract them. But I used the normal way to pass secrets.

Answer (score 1):

I was running into this issue. For me the culprit was the secret value in Github secrets. The secret had been created correctly, it had the correct value and name however Github actions could not find it for some reason. Deleting the secret and recreating it seems to have solved the issue though i cannot determine why

Comment: Maybe needed for old secrets. There are some nasty artifacts when using old acconuts, old secrets and old payed plans with github.