# Environments not working in called Workflow

Tags: github-actions

I have a workflow `cicd.yaml`, that gets triggered like so:

```yaml
on: push
```

In the jobs, I have interaction with Google Cloud via:

```yaml
jobs:
  infrastructure:
    environment: live
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: "google-github-actions/auth@v0"
      with:
        project_id: foo
        credentials_json: ${{ secrets.JSON }}
```

`JSON` is a secret on the `live` environment.

And this works fine.
When I now move `infrastructure` in another workflow `infrastructure.yaml` and call that it no longer works:

```yaml
jobs:
  caller:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/infrastructure.yaml
```

The error I get is:

> Error: google-github-actions/auth failed with: the GitHub Action workflow must specify exactly one of "workload_identity_provider" or "credentials_json"! If you are specifying input values via GitHub secrets, ensure the secret is being injected into the environment. By default, secrets are not passed to workflows triggered from forks, including Dependabot.

I assume there is some special handling of environments in called workflows but I have a hard time debugging whether `environment` worked at all.

BTW: the jobs block in `infrastructure.yaml` looks the same:

```yaml
jobs:
  infrastructure:
    environment: live
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: "google-github-actions/auth@v0"
      with:
        project_id: foo
        credentials_json: ${{ secrets.JSON }}
```

Comment: are you sure your problem is the environment and not the fact that you're not passing the secrets? If you want to inherit secrets, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72111842/1080523

Comment: You should it as official answer @rethab :)