# Why am I unable to access secrets from a repository in the same organization?

Tags: github-actions

I have a workflows repository and a main repository.
My reusable workflow is being called from my workflows repository and my workflows dispatch is being called from my main repository.

My dispatch in the main repository looks like this:

```
name: name_of_workflow

on:
 push:
  branches: github_branch

jobs:
 job1: 
  uses: org/repo/workflow_repo/.github/workflows/filenamehere
  with:
   variable_name: |
     -user=${{secrets.USER_NAME}}
     -password=${{secrets.USER_PASSWORD}}
```

Whenever I try to run the workflow I get an error that it can't access the secrets. Which makes sense to me because the secrets are being held in the workflows repository and they're encrypted. But is there a way that I can call those secrets into my main repo or am I sol and have to create those repos in my main repo?

Comment: You don't use inputs and secrets in reusable workflows that way. I suggest following the [official documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows#using-inputs-and-secrets-in-a-reusable-workflow) for examples. Note that a limitation is also that you can't use secrets directly on reusable workflows, you should inform them from the original workflow which call the reusable workflow.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Secrets doesnt pass from github action secrets to reusable workflow in github actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71047802/secrets-doesnt-pass-from-github-action-secrets-to-reusable-workflow-in-github-ac)

Comment: Thank you. I was able to access them by setting a env variable to my secret. Not sure I'll use this method because there are too many to make this a convenient solution.